Storage space/pool got error, DriveLetter only with raw format
everyone.
I have encountered some issues with the storage space.
I am in desperate need of your assistance, and your suggestions are crucial to me.
This storage space contains nearly 20 years of data, and unfortunately, I don't have any other backups.
I created on the Windows 11 Pro for Workstation Edition.（23585 Now)
My storage space is configured in a parity mode and consists of six hard drives: three WDC HDDs for storage (HDD-Tier), two 512GB NVMe drives for caching and tiered storage (SSD-Tier), and one 128GB NVMe drive used as a journal.

$ Get-PhysicalDisk | ft FriendlyName,DeviceId,BusType,UniqueId,Size,Usage,MediaType,CanPool -auto
FriendlyName                DeviceId BusType UniqueId                                       Size Usage       MediaType
------------                -------- ------- --------                                       ---- -----       ---------
WDC  WUH721816ALE6L4        2        SATA    5000CC2A95E627B4                     16000900661248 Auto-Select HDD
GLOWAY Basic128GNVMe-M.2/80 6        NVMe    eui.00000000000000000000010000000000   128035676160 Journal     SSD
WDC  WUH721816ALE6L4        0        SATA    5000CC2A95F0CC9F                     16000900661248 Auto-Select HDD
Colorful CN600 512GB WH     3        NVMe    eui.0000000000000001                   512110190592 Auto-Select SSD
Colorful CN600 512GB WH     4        NVMe    eui.0000000000000001                   512110190592 Auto-Select SSD
Netac NVMe SSD 128GB        5        NVMe    eui.00000000000000000000010000000000   128035676160 Auto-Select SSD
WDC  WUH721816ALE6L4        1        SATA    5000CC2A95F0C85E                     16000900661248 Auto-Select HDD


The entire storage space is presented as a virtual disk/volume and is assigned the drive letter Z: in my local settings.
The file system format is ReFS.
I have been using this disk array for almost two years now, and I had to rebuild it once after one of the  WDC HDD disk failure.
Last night, before going to bed, I heard annoying noises coming from one of the HDDs. However, when I checked the system, everything appeared to be normal. Nevertheless, the annoying  noise continued intermittently, so I shutdown the server.
When I checked the host this morning, I found that one of the WDC HDDs was marked as offline (the noise persisted). After contacting WDC customer support and providing them with a recording, they determined that the sound was coming from the head alignment and suggested that I replace the power cable (yes, two of the WDC HDDs are connected to the same power cable).
At this point, Z: was still accessible, and there were no error messages related to the storage space.
After connecting a new power cable and booting up the system again, the annoying noise disappeared.
I thought all the problems were resolved, but when I tried to open Z:, I received the following messages:

z:\ is not accessible.
The volume repair was not succseful.

In File Explorer, the status of Z: is displayed as 0 bytes for capacity/used space/free space.
In Disk Management, Z: is shown as being in RAW format.
Using Get-Volume in PowerShell, I found that the DriveLetter is still present, but information such as FilesystemType and OperationalStatus is missing.

$Get-Volume
DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining     Size

Z                        Unknown        Fixed     Healthy      Unknown                     0 B      0 B

In System > Storage > Storage Management > Storage Spaces, the status is displayed as OK, but there is a yellow exclamation mark indicating a warning.
In Disk & Volumes, the message states:

Storage Space: Online (No Label )
(Z:)
RAW

Based on my understanding, it seems that there might be an issue with the partition table of this virtual disk or volume.
I'm wondering if any of you have any methods that could assist me in recovering this data. It is truly important to me.
Really thank you.
